# python: loop array in stats.anova

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have the following line:

```
print(sm.stats.anova_lm(fitModelDict['1'], fitModelDict['2'], fitModelDict['3'], type=1))
```

I would like to know how the line can be written with a loop if I have:

```
 fitModelDict[i],i=10
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The closest to what you are wanting in python will be using [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
some_args = ['one', 'two', 'three']
my_function(*some_args)

# equivalent to:
my_function(some_args[0], some_args[1], some_args[2])
```

Or if the function can take keyword arguments, you can unpack dictionaries:

```
a = {'one':'1', 'two':'2', 'three':'3'}
my_function(**a)

# equivalent to:
my_function(one=1, two=2, three=3)
```

So, in your case, you could use a loop before the function call to build up a list of the arguments you want to use, and then use argument unpacking as above.